# Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I've installed community version of tar of Confluent Platform. I'm trying to use below command from ksql and getting below error

```
confluent version 
confluent - Confluent CLI

Version:     v1.40.0
Git Ref:     1c975456
Build Date:  2021-09-23T02:04:31Z
Go Version:  go1.16.3 (darwin/arm64)
Development: false

prateekashtikar@Prateeks-MacBook-Pro ksql-course-master % confluent local version
The local commands are intended for a single-node development environment only,
NOT for production usage. https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/index.html

Confluent Platform: 7.0.1
```

Command -

```
ksql> CREATE SOURCE CONNECTOR `postgres-jdbc-source` WITH (
>   "connector.class"='io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector',
>   "connection.url"='jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/postgres',
>   "mode"='incrementing',
>   "incrementing.column.name"='ref',
>   "table.whitelist"='carusers',
>   "connection.password"='postgres',
>   "connection.user"='postgres',
>   "topic.prefix"='db-',
>   "key"='username');
```

Error -

```
{
  "error_code" : 500,
  "message" : "Failed to find any class that implements Connector and which name matches io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector, available connectors are: PluginDesc{klass=class io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector, name='io.confluent.connect.replicator.ReplicatorSourceConnector', version='7.0.1', encodedVersion=7.0.1, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/kafka-connect-replicator/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector', version='1', encodedVersion=1, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/kafka/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockConnector', version='7.0.1-ce', encodedVersion=7.0.1-ce, type=connector, typeName='connector', location='file:/Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/confluent-kafka-mqtt/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSinkConnector', version='7.0.1-ce', encodedVersion=7.0.1-ce, type=sink, typeName='sink', location='file:/Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/confluent-kafka-mqtt/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.MockSourceConnector', version='7.0.1-ce', encodedVersion=7.0.1-ce, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/confluent-kafka-mqtt/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.SchemaSourceConnector', version='7.0.1-ce', encodedVersion=7.0.1-ce, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/confluent-kafka-mqtt/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSinkConnector', version='7.0.1-ce', encodedVersion=7.0.1-ce, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/confluent-kafka-mqtt/'}, PluginDesc{klass=class org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector, name='org.apache.kafka.connect.tools.VerifiableSourceConnector', version='7.0.1-ce', encodedVersion=7.0.1-ce, type=source, typeName='source', location='file:/Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/share/java/confluent-kafka-mqtt/'}"
} 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve by going to https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connectors/self-managed/confluent-hub/client.html#c-hub-client

```
confluent-hub install debezium/debezium-connector-postgresql:1.9.3
The component can be installed in any of the following Confluent Platform installations: 
  1. /Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1 (based on $CONFLUENT_HOME) 
  2. /Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1 (where this tool is installed) 
Choose one of these to continue the installation (1-2): 1
Do you want to install this into /Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/share/confluent-hub-components? (yN) y

 
Component's license: 
Apache 2.0 
https://github.com/debezium/debezium/blob/master/LICENSE.txt 
I agree to the software license agreement (yN) y

You are about to install 'debezium-connector-postgresql' from Debezium Community, as published on Confluent Hub. 
Do you want to continue? (yN) y

Downloading component Debezium PostgreSQL CDC Connector 1.9.3, provided by Debezium Community from Confluent Hub and installing into /Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/share/confluent-hub-components 
Detected Worker's configs: 
  1. Standard: /Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties 
  2. Standard: /Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties 
  3. Standard: /Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties 
  4. Standard: /Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties 
  5. Based on CONFLUENT_CURRENT: /var/folders/kn/4wr9__651l37hckxvnnwt4hh0000gn/T/confluent.218210/connect/connect.properties 
  6. Used by Connect process with PID 41219: /var/folders/kn/4wr9__651l37hckxvnnwt4hh0000gn/T/confluent.218210/connect/connect.properties 
Do you want to update all detected configs? (yN) y

Adding installation directory to plugin path in the following files: 
  /Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties 
  /Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/etc/kafka/connect-standalone.properties 
  /Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-distributed.properties 
  /Users/prats/confluent-7.0.1/etc/schema-registry/connect-avro-standalone.properties 
  /var/folders/kn/4wr9__651l37hckxvnnwt4hh0000gn/T/confluent.218210/connect/connect.properties 
  /var/folders/kn/4wr9__651l37hckxvnnwt4hh0000gn/T/confluent.218210/connect/connect.properties 
 
Completed
```